# Gremlin querying language tutorial `as` filter

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

In this tutorial

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/getting-started/

```
gremlin> g.V().as('a').out().as('b').out().as('c').
           select('a','b','c')
==>[a:v[1],b:v[4],c:v[5]]
==>[a:v[1],b:v[4],c:v[3]]
```

I don't understand what `g.V().as('a')` means, does it qualify ALL vertices as "a", or iterates each vertex and for each iteration calls one vertex "a"?

This is the graph

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is a step label. It means that `V()` is named "a" and the first `out()` is named "b" and the second `out()` is named "c". The step label enables you to access the traverser currently at that step (in this case with `select()`).

So on the first iteration of the traversal, you first find `v[1]`. Gremlin traverses `out()` from there and he gets to `v[4]`. He traverses `out()` from there and he gets to `v[5]`. So, `v[5]` is the output:

```
gremlin> g.V().as('a').out().as('b').out().as('c').next()
==>v[5]
```

but, if you want to know what was at `V()` for this first iteration you can reference the step which we can see is `v[1]`:

```
gremlin> g.V().as('a').out().as('b').out().as('c').select('a').next()
==>v[1]
```

or, if we want to see what was at every step as was done in the example:

```
gremlin> g.V().as('a').out().as('b').out().as('c').select('a','b','c').next()
==>a=v[1]
==>b=v[4]
==>c=v[5]
```

which is basically analogous to:

```
gremlin> g.V().out().out().path().next()
==>v[1]
==>v[4]
==>v[5]
```